Return type are not matched for some value classes
When mocking function returns some primitive value class, assertion failed.
I guess the reason is representation of value class. Are there any workarounds?
Version:

Kotlin: 1.9.23
MockK: 1.3.10

AssertionFailed case
@JvmInline
value class LongValueClass(val value: Long)

@JvmInline
value class StringValueClass(val value: String)

interface ValueGetter {
    suspend fun getLong(): LongValueClass
    suspend fun getString(): StringValueClass
}

class ValueGetterTest {
    private val someClass = mockk<ValueGetter>()

    // --- Failed test
    @Test
    fun testLong() = runTest {
        coEvery { someClass.getLong() } returns LongValueClass(2)
        assertEquals(LongValueClass(2), someClass.getLong())
    }

    // --- Succeeded test
    @Test
    fun testString() = runTest {
        coEvery { someClass.getString() } returns StringValueClass("test")
        assertEquals(StringValueClass("test"), someClass.getString())
    }
}

This test finish unsuccessfully with this error:
Expected :LongValueClass(value=2)
Actual   :2

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: expected: <LongValueClass(value=2)> but was: <2>


ClassCastException case
interface ValueGetter {
    suspend fun getLong(): LongValueClass
    suspend fun getString(): StringValueClass
}

interface ValueService {
    suspend fun <T> modifyValue(value: T): T
}

class ValueUseCase(private val valueGetter: ValueGetter, private val valueService: ValueService) {
    suspend fun doubleLong(): LongValueClass {
        val value = valueGetter.getLong()
        return valueService.modifyValue(value)
    }

    suspend fun getReversedString(): StringValueClass {
        val value = valueGetter.getString()
        return valueService.modifyValue(value)
    }
}

class ValueUseCaseTest {
    private val valueGetter = mockk<ValueGetter>()
    private val valueService = mockk<ValueService>()

    private val valueUseCase = ValueUseCase(valueGetter, valueService)

    // --- Failed test
    @Test
    fun testLong() = runTest {
        coEvery { valueGetter.getLong() } returns LongValueClass(10)
        coEvery { valueService.modifyValue<LongValueClass>(any()) } returns LongValueClass(100)

        assertEquals(
            LongValueClass(100),
            valueUseCase.doubleLong()
        )
    }
    
    // --- Succeeded test
    @Test
    fun testString() = runTest {
        coEvery { valueGetter.getString() } returns StringValueClass("lorem ipsum")
        coEvery { valueService.modifyValue<StringValueClass>(any()) } returns StringValueClass("mocked!")

        assertEquals(
            StringValueClass("mocked!"),
            valueUseCase.getReversedString()
        )
    }
}

ValueUseCaseTest.testLong() function fails with:
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Long cannot be cast to class com.example.LongValueClass (java.lang.Long is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; com.example.LongValueClass is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.example.ValueUseCase.doubleLong-6JExesc(ValueUseCase.kt:5)
    at com.example.ValueUseCaseTest$testLong$1.invokeSuspend(ValueUseCaseTest.kt:22)
    at com.example.ValueUseCaseTest$testLong$1.invoke(ValueUseCaseTest.kt)
    at com.example.ValueUseCaseTest$testLong$1.invoke(ValueUseCaseTest.kt)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:316)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestDispatcher.processEvent$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestDispatcher.kt:24)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestCoroutineScheduler.tryRunNextTaskUnless$kotlinx_coroutines_test(TestCoroutineScheduler.kt:99)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt$runTest$2$1$workRunner$1.invokeSuspend(TestBuilders.kt:322)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.EventLoopImplBase.processNextEvent(EventLoop.common.kt:277)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BlockingCoroutine.joinBlocking(Builders.kt:95)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking(Builders.kt:69)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Builders.kt:48)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.runBlocking$default(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersJvmKt.createTestResult(TestBuildersJvm.kt:10)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:310)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(TestBuilders.kt:168)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0(Unknown Source)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt__TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(TestBuilders.kt:160)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.test.TestBuildersKt.runTest-8Mi8wO0$default(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.ValueUseCaseTest.testLong(ValueUseCaseTest.kt:16)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:725)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:131)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:149)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:140)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:84)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:106)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:64)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:45)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:37)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$7(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:214)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:210)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:151)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1596)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:119)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:94)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:89)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:103)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:580)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:113)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:65)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)

Whole reproducible project: https://github.com/k-ogawa-1988/kotlin-mockk-value-class

Seems to be a known issue. https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/249

Also might be related: https://github.com/mockk/mockk/issues/813
